# Typescript angular 2 ng-book syntax

Tags: typescript, angular

Can anyone explain me what stand for:

```
Subject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
```

in

```
export class UserService {
  // `currentUser` contains the current user
  currentUser: Subject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  public setCurrentUser(newUser: User): void {
    this.currentUser.next(newUser);
  }
}
```

please :)

I don't understand the usage of ts type in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` inherits from `Subject`.  From the point of view of users of the service, they don't care, but a `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with an initial value, hence the `null` argument to the constructor.  Any class that subscribes to it will immediately get a value, `null` in this case, even before `.next` is called on it.

As for `User` in `Subject<User>`, `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` are [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  This lets you know what type they are operating with and when you subscribe to them you can get the code completion because your development environment knows what type it is getting.